# Android alert dialog Issue

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

In my android application, I use one alert dialog to display some information to the user, and if the user click the dialog , it should finish the activity. My code is

```
offer.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(offer.this).create();
    alert.setTitle("SVSugar Mill");
    alert.setMessage("Offer Number is "+offer_no.getText().toString());
    alert.setButton("Click to Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        //return;
        }
    });
    alert.show();
    }
});
```

It doesn't wait for the user response to finish(). Instead it will be called even if the user didn't click the Alert dialog. I know this is asynchronous, but I need to do this.(The OfferNO should be displayed to the user. When the user click the alert dialog it should finish the activity). Is there any way to do this?

Someone help me

Edit:

The activity will be finished without waiting for the user to click the alert dialog

Comment: so what is the problem here?

Comment: It doesn't wait for the user response to finish()

Comment: your question is not clear buddy.

Comment: So what you want is dialog appears-> wait for 5 sec-> if user press button finish activity and dont wait further or if user dont press button finish activity after 5 seconds. Is that what you want.

Comment: I dont need it for 5seconds, It only finish the activity when the user click the button

Comment: Build a dialog-box outside UIthread and then .show() it on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ShowDialog(final Context context) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(android.R.string.dialog_alert_title)  
                .setMessage(UContext.getContext().getString(R.string.network_error))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                this.finish();
                            }
                        }).show();
    }
```

Comment: It didn't solve my issue, It doesn't wait for the user to click

Comment: Please remove runonUIThread from your code and simply out this. i guess your activity is closing before executing this code.

Comment: I run some other code, I use Progress dialog. Thats why I use runOnUIThread

Comment: Debug and check which thing is finishing your activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you created two AlertDialog instances here:

```
alertDialog=builder.create();
builder.create().show();
```

Then you called dismiss() on the dialog that is not actually shown. This should fix the problem:

```
alertDialog=builder.show();
```